# Trending SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, trend

So what I am trying to do is make a trending algorithm, i need help with the SQL code as i cant get it to go.

There are three aspects to the algorithm: (I am completely open to ideas on a better trend algorithm)

```
1.Plays during 24h / Total plays of the song
2.Plays during 7d / Total plays of the song 
3.Plays during 24h / The value of plays of the most played item over 24h (whatever item leads the play count over 24h)
```

Each aspect is to be worth 0.33, for a maximum value of 1.0 being possible.

The third aspect is necessary as newly uploaded items would automatically be at top place unless their was a way to drop them down.

The table is called aud_plays and the columns are:

```
PlayID: Just an auto-incrementing ID for the table
AID: The id of the song
IP: ip address of the user listening
time: UNIX time code
```

I have tried a few sql codes but im pretty stuck being unable to get this to work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you go into more detail? All I hear is algorithm, .33, and SQL.

Comment: Sure, I want a SQL query to determine what song is trending versus other songs.  What I had in mind was three values each worth 0.33 maximum.  The sum of these three values will be ordered to determine the highest trending song.  Currently I want the three 0.33 values of the query to be determined by 24h plays/total plays of the song, 7day plays/total plays of the song, and 24h plays/the 24h play count of the song which has the most plays over the 24h

Comment: Can you post the SQL code you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

**In your ?aud_songs? (the one the AID points to) table add the following columns**

- Last24hrPlays INT -- use BIGINT if you plan on getting billion+
- Last7dPlays INT
- TotalPlays INT

**In your aud_plays table create an AFTER INSERT trigger that will increment aud_song.TotalPlays.**

```
UPDATE aud_song SET TotalPlays = TotalPlays + 1 WHERE id = INSERTED.aid
```

**Calculating your trending in real time for every request would be taxing on your server**, so it's best to just run a job to update the data every ~5 minutes. So create a SQL Agent Job to run every X minutes that updates Last7dPlays and Last24hrPlays.

```
UPDATE aud_songs SET Last7dPlays = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aud_plays WHERE aud_plays.aid = aud_songs.id AND aud_plays.time BETWEEN GetDate()-7 AND GetDate()), 
    Last24hrPlays = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aud_plays WHERE aud_plays.aid = aud_songs.id AND aud_plays.time BETWEEN GetDate()-1 AND GetDate())
```

**I would also recommend removing old records from aud_plays** (possibly older than 7days since you will have the TotalPlays trigger.

It should be easy to figure out how to calculate your 1 and 2 (from the question). Here's the SQL for 3.

```
SELECT cast(Last24hrPlays as float) / (SELECT MAX(Last24hrPlays) FROM aud_songs) FROM aud_songs WHERE aud_songs.id = @ID
```

**NOTE** I made the T-SQL pretty generic and unoptimized to illustrate how the process works.